# Shopify blog post create a thumbnail image

Tags: blogs, shopify, liquid

I am using shopify to power my website. I am having trouble using the blog. Can anyone assist me trying to set up a thumbnail for each blog post on the page where all your post are listed? 
Here is the code I have so far but this just displays each post's title and data posted.

```
    {% for article in blog.articles %}
      <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ 'blogs.article.read_more' | t }} →</a> 
      <time pubdate datetime="{{ article.published_at | date: '%Y-%m-%d' }}">
        {{ article.published_at | date: format: 'month_day_year' }}
      </time>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add the image to the add excerpt section then in liquid you go
     {{ article.excerpt }}